# how to compare the prediction of two models using statistical significant test python

Tags: python, dataframe

basically I have the age prediction from one model:

```
df_baseline    userid|y_pred
                 12  |29
                 13  |35
                 14  |32 
                 15  |39
                 .....
```

and I have the prediction from the second model:

```
df_final       userid|age
                 12  |31
                 13  |34
                 14  |32 
                 15  |21
                 ....
```

how can I perform a statistical significant test to check that df_final prediction performs better than df_baseline prediction?

I thought about using Null hypothesis testing but I know this one checks if the two samples are significantly different or not so I am lost what to do here

Comment: Statistics questions belong on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Null hypothesis testing on both predictions and then compare their p_values with each other